# How implement the PHP strip_tags in the Joomla 4-file com_content/archive/default_items.php

Tags: php, template-override, joomla-4

In Joomla 4.3.1, I've made an override of the com_content/archive/default_items.php
Now I want to strip tags and display the string (text from article) as one line `<p>` only. Without any formatting. No `<strong>, <em>, <br>, <h3>` etc.

This is the code where I somewhere want to add the string function "**strip_tags**":

```
<?php if ($params->get('show_intro')) : ?>
    <div class="intro" itemprop="articleBody">
        <?php echo HTMLHelper::_('string.truncateComplex', $item->introtext, $params->get('introtext_limit')); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It goes without saying I'm a PHP-beginner, and I've researched the PHP- and Joomla-forums. Googling the "truncateComplex" does not really give anything. And all my attemps just break my site.

Answer (score 0):

1. One way:

   ```
   $stripIntro = strip_tags( value, $item->introtext );
   ```

   then

   ```
   HTMLHelper::_('string.truncateComplex',$stripIntro, $params->get('introtext_limit'); ?>
   ```
2. Or another way:

   ```
   $stripIntro = HTMLHelper::_('string.truncateComplex',$item->introtext, $params->get('introtext_limit'); ?>
   ```

   then strip tags

   ```
   echo strip_tags(value, $stripIntro);
   ```